# Can't get data from request with drop_down webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm beginning in python.Now I'm use request for get data in BOT website 
I need got Loan Rates but in request it retrieve data in Deposit Rates for Individuals.
[Deposit Rates for Individuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPmxo.png)

[Loan Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hoWj.png)

[My code get data from Deposit Rates for Individuals not Loan Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WfRS.png)

[My code get data from Deposit Rates for Individuals not Loan Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiK30.png)

[Page Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzAm.png)

This's my first time in StackOverflow.I sincerely apologize for having overlooked the issue but im new user and i don't have reputation point.So I can't post full photo.

Comment: "Can you solve this problem" is not really a question anyone else can answer

Comment: I sincerely apologize for having overlooked the issue but im new user in Stackoverflow and i don't have reputation point.So I can't post full photo.

Comment: @veerachai you should post your code as `TEXT` and we will help to format it. also you didn't mention your goal. do you want the output as `CSV` or what.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you didn't provided us with your desired output.

Actually you are doing `GET` request for a website which is taken data from you as `POST` and that's happens once you click on `Loan Rates`.

Here's a quick `Selenium` approach

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bot.or.th/English/Statistics/FinancialMarkets/Interestrate/_layouts/application/interest_rate/IN_Rate.aspx")
invest = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_rdoType_1"]').click()

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

print(df)
```

Also you can do simple script like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

print("Insert Date In The Following Format\nDD/MM/YYYY")

date = input(">: ")
df = pd.read_csv(
    f"https://www.bot.or.th/English/Statistics/FinancialMarkets/Interestrate/_layouts/application/interest_rate/Download_IN_Rate.aspx?fType=CSV&qDate={date}&qINType=1", delimiter="|")


df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Also you can do it via `POST` request, something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = {
# here you will need to put the POST data, you can retreive that from your browser dev-tools. by location network-tab for the url during POST.
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.bot.or.th/English/Statistics/FinancialMarkets/Interestrate/_layouts/application/interest_rate/IN_Rate.aspx", data=data)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.findAll("td", {'class': 'tx-news txt-align-left'}):
    print(item.text)
```